# I wish to know if my collapsing toolbar is scrolled half its initial height, i m aware of the onoffsetchanged method

Tags: android

I wish to know if my collapsing toolbar is scrolled half its initial height, i m aware of the onoffsetchanged method, can someone help me achieve that

```
 @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (scrollRange == -1) {
                scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                Log.e("hi", "this is "+ scrollRange);
            }
            if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle("");
                tv_title_bar_event_desc.setText(st_title_bar_event_desc);
                isShow = true;
            } else if (appBarLayout.getHeight()<=200) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle("");
                relativeLayout_event_desc_extra_toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.e("when", "collapsedhalf");
                tv_title_bar_event_desc.setText(st_title_bar_event_desc);

            } else if (isShow) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle("");
                relativeLayout_event_desc_extra_toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tv_title_bar_event_desc.setText("");
                isShow = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

well what i have tried is this approach, but this isnt very smooth

```
 @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (scrollRange == -1) {
                scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                Log.e("hi", "this is "+ scrollRange);
            }
            if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle("");
                tv_title_bar_event_desc.setText(st_title_bar_event_desc);
                isShow = true;
            } else if (scrollRange + verticalOffset <=100) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle("");
                relativeLayout_event_desc_extra_toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.e("when", "collapsedhalf");
                tv_title_bar_event_desc.setText(st_title_bar_event_desc);

            } else if (scrollRange + verticalOffset >=100) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle("");
                relativeLayout_event_desc_extra_toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.e("when", "uncollapsedhalf");
                tv_title_bar_event_desc.setText(st_title_bar_event_desc);

            } else if (isShow) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle("");
                relativeLayout_event_desc_extra_toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tv_title_bar_event_desc.setText("");
                isShow = false;
            }
        }
    });
```